# How to add / alter symbol index capacilty after table is created?

Tags: questdb

I have a table in QuestDB which I created with symbol columns. I added index after that as per documentations as

```
ALTER TABLE tbl ALTER COLUMN instrument ADD INDEX;
```

Now I realize I'd like to specify index capacity to try turn the performance. I looked at the documentation and cannot find a way to specify index capacity apart from the table create statement. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify capacity when you add index to existing table

```
ALTER TABLE x ADD COLUMN abc SYMBOL INDEX CAPACITY 123
```

you cannot alter capacity once index is created, at least in v6. Y